# Retrieve all nodes of a IVsHierarchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I am searching for a way to get all the child nodes of a given `IVsHierarchy`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) itself I can't see any way to get a list of all items, just a way to get the properties of any item with the [`GetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.getproperty?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsHierarchy_GetProperty_System_UInt32_System_Int32_System_Object__) method. Which has a parameter named `itemid`, which from my understanding should be fed with an unique id of any of its nodes. Anyhow as per documentation it should be of type [VSConstants.VSITEMID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsitemid?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), but this kinda doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any given node, you'll need to iterate the tree structure by invoking IVsHierarchy.GetProperty with __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstChild and __VSHPROPID_VSHPROPID_NextSibling.

There are a couple of examples hidden in the [archived SCC extensibility samples](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/c6b80a4ff7023578649d7edecc8fd6cd8a34da10/ArchivedSamples). That you may be able to use for additional guidance.

Sincerely,
Ed Dore

Comment: My god, I thought they would keep it all in the `VSITEMID` enum, but as always, they don't.